# Como formatar o helpers do mvc de acordo com o meu layout Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou tentando de várias formas ajustar o layout de acordo com o Helpers

```html
          <!-- rightpanel3  -->
            <div data-role="panel" id="opcoesusuario" data-position="right" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a">


            <a  class="ui-btn ui-mini" data-rel="close" data-transition="flip"  data-role="button" >@Html.ActionLink("Perguntas ","index","PerguntasRespondidas")</a>




      </div><!-- /rightpanel3 -->
```

Comment: Fiz desta forma, funcionou!

   <a href="/PerguntasRespondidas"  class="ui-btn ui-mini" data-rel="close" data-transition="flip"  data-role="button" >Perguntas Realizadas</a>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar os parametros como htmlAttributes.

Para fazer isso, utilize a sobrecarga `@Html.ActionLink("texto ancora", "Action", "Controller", new { htmlAtributtes })`

Exemplo:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Perguntas", "Index", "PerguntasRespondidas", new { @class="ui-btn ui-mini", data_rel="close", data_transition="flip",  data_role="button"  })
```

Observações:

1. A palavra `class` é uma palavra reservada. Então quando passar uma classe css como htmlAttribute utilize a sintaxe `@class="sua-classe"` o MVC saberá como renderiza-la na View.
2. htmlAttributes é um `object` para o compilador, logo o nome de suas propriedade não podem contar alguns caracteres. como o hífen. Por isso os atributos `data-` do html devem ser escritos como `data_`. Novamente o MVC faz a sua parte e renderiza como `data-`

Logo o exemplo acima seria renderizado como:

```
<a class="ui-btn ui-mini" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" href="/PerguntasRespondidas/Index/">Perguntas</a>
```

Exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KWLSeF